How to use ipywebrtc to stream audio to Azure Speech?
I'm using Solara to build a web app with Python, and I can use ipywebrtc to capture audio from the client's browser. I can first record the audio to a temporary file and then pass it to Azure Speech, but I need it to be streaming
At first, I tried with this code
from ipywebrtc import CameraStream, AudioRecorder
from azure.cognitiveservices.speech.audio import AudioInputStream
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
...
speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription="...", region="brazilsouth")

camera = CameraStream(constraints={'audio': True, 'video': False})
recorder = AudioRecorder(stream=camera)
stream = AudioInputStream(recorder.audio)
audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(stream=stream)
conversation_transcriber = speechsdk.transcription.ConversationTranscriber(speech_config=speech_config,audio_config=audio_config)
...

Exception in thread Thread-22 (recognize_from_device):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\threading.py", line 1073, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\threading.py", line 1010, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "L:\projects\testes\functions\ouvir_microfone.py", line 62, in recognize_from_device
    audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(stream=stream)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "L:\projects\testes\venv\Lib\site-packages\azure\cognitiveservices\speech\audio.py", line 382, in __init__
    _call_hr_fn(fn=_sdk_lib.audio_config_create_audio_input_from_stream, *[ctypes.byref(handle), stream._handle])
  File "L:\projects\testes\venv\Lib\site-packages\azure\cognitiveservices\speech\interop.py", line 61, in _call_hr_fn
    hr = fn(*args) if len(args) > 0 else fn()
         ^^^^^^^^^
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: TypeError: Don't know how to convert parameter 2
Exception ignored in: <function _Handle.__del__ at 0x00000140E12B5E40>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "L:\projects\testes\venv\Lib\site-packages\azure\cognitiveservices\speech\interop.py", line 105, in __del__
    elif self.__test_fn(self.__handle):
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: TypeError: Don't know how to convert parameter 1

changing AudioInputStream(recorder.audio) to AudioInputStream(recorder.codecs):
RuntimeError: Exception with error code:
[CALL STACK BEGIN]

    > GetModuleObject
    - audio_config_get_audio_processing_options
    - audio_config_create_audio_input_from_stream
    - ffi_prep_go_closure
    - ffi_call_go
    - ffi_call
    - 00007FF910133DD5 (SymFromAddr() error: Attempt to access invalid address.)
    - 00007FF910132D33 (SymFromAddr() error: Attempt to access invalid address.)
    - 00007FF910132928 (SymFromAddr() error: Attempt to access invalid address.)
    - PyObject_Call
    - PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
    - PyFunction_Vectorcall
    - PyObject_VectorcallMethod
    - PyObject_Vectorcall
    - PyObject_Vectorcall
    - PyEval_EvalFrameDefault

[CALL STACK END]

Exception with an error code: 0x5 (SPXERR_INVALID_ARG)


Can you share your complete code in the question

I could stream the audio in the browser and convert it to text with the Solara package using flask.

I could capture audio from the web browser using Solara, save it to a temporary file, and stream it directly to Azure Speech for continuous recognition.
Code :
app.py :
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
from threading import Timer
import solara
import pyaudio
import wave
import threading

app = Flask(__name__)

subscription_key = "<speech_key>"
service_region = "<speech_region>"
speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=subscription_key, region=service_region)
audio_config = speechsdk.AudioConfig(use_default_microphone=True)

chunks = []
recognition_running = False
recognizer = None
stop_timer = None
INACTIVITY_TIMEOUT = 5  

FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 16000
CHUNK = 1024
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"

audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
frames = []

def recognized_callback(evt):
    global chunks, stop_timer
    if evt.result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
        chunks.append(evt.result.text)
        print(f"Recognized: {evt.result.text}")
        reset_stop_timer()

def reset_stop_timer():
    global stop_timer
    if stop_timer:
        stop_timer.cancel()
    stop_timer = Timer(INACTIVITY_TIMEOUT, stop_recognition)
    stop_timer.start()

def start_recognition():
    global recognition_running, recognizer, audio_stream, frames
    if not recognition_running:
        recognition_running = True
        recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)
        recognizer.recognized.connect(recognized_callback)
        recognizer.start_continuous_recognition()
        print("Recognition started")

        frames = []
        audio_stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS,
                                  rate=RATE, input=True,
                                  frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
        threading.Thread(target=record_audio).start()

def record_audio():
    global audio_stream, frames, recognition_running
    while recognition_running:
        data = audio_stream.read(CHUNK)
        frames.append(data)

def stop_recognition():
    global recognition_running, recognizer, audio_stream, frames
    if recognition_running:
        recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()
        recognition_running = False
        print("Recognition stopped")

        audio_stream.stop_stream()
        audio_stream.close()
        wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
        wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
        wf.setsampwidth(audio.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
        wf.setframerate(RATE)
        wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
        wf.close()
        print(f"Audio saved as {WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME}")

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/start_recognition')
def start_recognition_route():
    start_recognition()
    return jsonify({'status': 'started'})

@solara.component
def MainPage():
    return solara.Column(
        [
            solara.Button("Start Recognition", on_click=start_recognition),
            solara.Text(f"Recognized: {', '.join(chunks)}")
        ]
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)

templates/index.html :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Azure Speech Service with Flask</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Speak into your microphone</h1>
    <button onclick="startRecognition()">Start Recognition</button>
    <pre id="recognized_text"></pre>
    <script>
        let recognitionStarted = false;
        function startRecognition() {
            fetch('/start_recognition')
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    console.log('Recognition started');
                    recognitionStarted = true;
                });
        }
        function handleRecognitionResults() {
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>

Output :
I got the below output in the browser with the output URL. I clicked on Start Recognition button and spoke some sentences.

VS code terminal output :
The audio from the web browser was saved to a .wav file and got the streamed text output with the audio in the vs code terminal as shown below.

